# Two false equalities

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I have to prove that the following equalities are not valid.

> **First.** Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $$[a,b)=\bigsqcup_{k=1}^n (a_k,b_k],$$
> where $-\infty<a_k<b_k<+\infty$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

**Proof.**
If this were true there would be only one $k_0\in\{1,\dots, n\}$ such that $a\in (a_{k_0}, b_{k_0}]$ and therefore $a>a_{k_0}$. On the other hand, $(a_{k_0}, b_{k_0}]\subset [a, b)$, but $a_{k_0}\notin[a,b)$ since $a_{k_0}<a.$

***Thanks to the suggestions I conclude that:***

$\sup{[a,b)}=b$ and $\sup{\sqcup_{k=1}^n (a_k,b_k]}=b_n$ (We can assume without affecting the generality that $b_1< b_2<\dots< b_n$), then $b_n=b$ and therefore $b\in \sqcup_{k=1}^n (a_k,b_k]$, but $b\notin [a,b)$.

> **Second.** Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
> $$(a,b)=\bigsqcup_{k=1}^n(a_k,b_k],$$
> where $-\infty<a_k<b_k<+\infty$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

**Proof.** If this were true there would be only one $k_0\in\{1,\dots, n\}$ such that $b\in (a_{k_0}, b_{k_0}]$, then $b\le b_{k_0}$. On the other hand we have tha $(a_{k_0}, b_{k_0}]\subset (a,b)$, but $b_{k_0}\notin (a.b)$. since $b_{k_0}\ge b$.

Are they formally correct? Thanks!

Comment: In the first, $a_{k_0}\notin(a_{k_0},b_{k_0}]$ is *also true*, so you've not really got a contradiction yet. In the second, $b\notin (a,b)$, so why would it be in any of the disjoint intervals?

Comment: As a hint, what can you say about the supremum and infimum of the intervals $[a,b)$ and $(a,b)$, and what about the supremum and infimum of the disjoint unions?

Comment: Dear @Mike there are two equalities which are evidently not true and the exercise consists in proving formally that they are actually not true.

Comment: The way I'd approach: can you reason why $[a,b)$ has no maximum?  Can you reason why $\bigsqcup\limits_{k=1}^n(a_k,b_k]$ does have a maximum?  Since the one does not have a maximum and the other does, can you reason that they must not be equal?

Comment: @Mike the way I interpret the question is that they are essentially asking for a proof why a half-open interval closed on the left can not be written as a disjoint union of half-open intervals all closed on the right.

Comment: Alright, I see it now

Comment: I do apologize @NatMath for not understanding the question earlier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do see your approach now now, but for the first, you would have to finish by saying that there is an $a'<a$ in $\bigsqcup_{k=1}^n (a_k,b_k]$; namely, $a' = (a_{k_0}+\min\{b_{k_0},a\})/2$ would do [so in particular, $a_{k_0} < a'<a$].

Your approach for your second does not work and I am not sure how one would fix. The problem is that why is there exactly one $k_0$ such that $b \in (a_{k_0},b_{k_0}]$.

How I'd approach *both* instead--and this proof does not assume disjointedness of the $(a_k,b_k]$s:

First note that $\bigsqcup_{k=1}^n (a_k,b_k]$ has a maximum element for any such choice of the $a_k$s and $b_k$s, whereas $(a,b)$ clearly does not have a maximum element and neither does $[a,b)$; indeed the maximum element of $\bigsqcup_{k=1}^n (a_k,b_k]$ is $\max\{b_1,b_2,\ldots, b_n\}$. So there is no way the first nor the second equation can be true for any such choice of the $a_k$s and $b_k$s.